# How do you evaluate whether design patterns are being effectively used at your organization?

Tags: design-patterns, evaluation

I've been advocating the knowledge of (and hopefully the use of) Design Patterns at my company.
I'd like some guidance on how I can show that through using design patterns in projects and solutions we're producing better products.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there's any other way than the old-fashioned way; that is, to show results.  Show that the process has improved via metrics (delivery dates, estimate accuracy, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree that just by using design patterns you are producing better products. Using the *right* design-pattern in the *right* situation might produce better results.

I think that you should instead tell your co-workers and management that by applying Test Driven Development you will produce better software and in order to create testable code you need to apply design-patterns.

Maybe you should show them one open-source project with a good test-coverage and explain why it matters (reduce regression bugs etc.) and then show them by example why they used this or that design-pattern and explain why it matters from a testing point of view.